# Angular js increment decrements with popover

Tags: angularjs

Had done some code on angular.js for creating the following customized component Bump Up/ Bump Down middle menu container when clicks on the middle field.

present middle field is working fine + - is not working which we have to used for bump up/ down the same values.

Thx in advance.[Code link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSzBXRcvUqD7RKLU9byW?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code , if I understood your requirement clearly. See it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaKIl9I1WBzRjAZC7dCT?p=preview)

Added a function

```
 var findIndex = function(currentColor, colorArray){
       var index = 0;
       for(var i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
         if(currentColor.name == colorArray[i].name){
           index = i;
           return index;
         }
       }

       return index;

      }
```

And on decrement or increment

```
 scope.decrementclick = function() {
       var index = findIndex(scope.currentColor, scope.colors);
       if(index > 0){
         index--;
       }
       scope.selectColor(scope.colors[index]);

         //alert("down clicked");
     };
```

Comment: can you make the hide middle popover when the selection done from the middle popover container.